# How to convert an array of decimal values in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to change [1,2,3,4] into [1 0 0 0;0 1 0 0;0 0 1 0;0 0 0 1]  in matlab, what is a way to achieve this?

Given:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

I need:

```
[1 0 0 0;0 1 0 0;0 0 1 0;0 0 0 1]
```

Comment: This is a bit ambiguous. The easy answer is [`eye(4)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eye.html). You need to fill in more detail about what you're looking for and what you've tried so far.

Comment: @BenD how's this related to binary? I'd agree with you on the `1` and `2`, but `3` is definitely `1100`, not `0010`

Comment: @BenD it's not really binary, it look like one-hot encoding.

Comment: Those aren't binary values...

Comment: Ah, you're right I spoke to soon.

Comment: I’m sorry  what if a =[1,2,4,4,2,4,5,7.....] how to change it

Comment: @ w404336713 craigim is right that you'll need more detail. For example, should each result have a digit count equal to the length of the original array or equal to the size of the largest entry?

i.e. given [1,5] can we assume you want [ 10000, 00001 ] ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078287/create-a-zero-filled-2d-array-with-ones-at-positions-indexed-by-a-vector and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38947948/how-can-i-hot-one-encode-in-matlab

Answer (score 2):

```
out=zeros(size(input,1),max(input));
for i=1:size(input,1)
  out(i,input(i))=1;
end
```

Use this with the assumption that input is a column vector.